# How to classify dashboards in a list under one application in splunk

Tags: splunk-dashboard

I have a multiple dashboards and I want to list them to come under one specific application. How to classify this dashboards ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dropdown menu with your dashboards go to *Settings » User interface » Navigation menus* and edit the default app navigation

Use a *collection* to group your views under the same drop-down. Well, instead of alerts, reports, datasets fill in the names of dashboards from your app.

```
  <collection label="My Custom Category" >
    <view name="alerts" />
    <view name="reports" />
    <view name="datasets" />
  </collection>
```

[image]